# Path is missing in KeystoneJS

Tags: keystonejs

In the Keystone Admin, I modified the `Post.js` by adding an input field `category`. But when creating a new post, it throw an error like below.

> There was an error creating the new Post:
>
> Path `category` is required.

Any idea what the the `Path` it refers to ? And how to add a Path?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Your focus shouldn't be on the path but on the missing `category` field. Please show code.